# What does argument in listen function do?

Tags: python, sockets

I saw an example of using the socket module in python and I saw a line of code like this:

```
s.listen(5)
```

What does the 5 mean? Google doesn’t have an answer.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen

Comment: Google doesn't have an answer?  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html  That says your server can accept no more than 5 connections at a time.

Comment: Don’t ask Google. Ask the documentation.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html is a good read if you're going to be doing something with sockets

Comment: [google "argument to socket listen"](https://www.google.com/search?q=argument+to+socket+listen&oq=argument+to+socket+listen&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160j33i22i29i30.6910j1j2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) does have the answer

Answer (score -1):

listen() marks the socket referred to by sockfd as a passive socket, that is, as a socket that will be used to accept incoming connection requests using accept(2)

Comment: If you want to answer the question that was asked, you should add to your answer an explanation of what the argument passed to listen() does.